# How to distribute apk for the ARCH in Google Play?

Tags: android, architecture, java-native-interface, google-play

I have application (apk) that uses native code (.so in libs/armeabi, libs/x86 etc). I'd like to distribute separate apk for the ARCH as it will be too large if it contains libs for all the archs. How can i do it? Can i build the app for the arch and upload them to Google Play one-by-one to let Google Play select apk for the arch automatically? APK expansions files are not suitable as the app can have only 2 files but i need 3 archs at least. How does Google Play understand the apk is for armeabi f.e (if it contains only libs/armeabi .so-files)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To upload one APK for each arch, you need to create these APKs with different version codes. (`android:versionCode` inside your manifest).

The store will deliver to the user the compatible APK with the higher version code, and there is no downgrade. So you need to respect this rule: **x86 APK version number > ARMv7 APK version number > ARMv5 APK version number > version numbers you were using before having multiple APKs**.

The store will understand the APK is for a specific arch if you have the associated libs/ARCH folder inside your APK.

When you upload your APKs to the store, you first need to switch to **advanced mode**:
[image: advanced mode switch on Google Play Store]

then you can upload all the APKs you want, with different ARCH support and different version codes. Once its done you'll see a summary with the version codes and differences between the APKs that are uploaded, and you will not be able to go back to simple mode:
[image: multiple APKs on Google Play Store]

Comment: one more question: so i have to exclude all other arch libs folders except one (to make apk targeted to this one arch)?

Comment: Yes. Your package will be targeted to any arch libs folders it contains.